# Creating local remote git repo

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-remote

sorry if this has been answered somewhere but my hour of searching was fruitless.

Im trying to set up an auto-build repo for my application on a local machine. My goal is to have my normal git repo for development and collaboration and then once it is ready for a build to push to a remote repo on a local machine that will use a hook to trigger an auto-build.

My problem is trying to create a remote repo on my local machine. I had no problem creating a remote repo using a git URL but I'm not sure how to go about setting up a local repo that is accessible by ssh keys.

From what I've read it should be something like this:

`git remote add buildrepo user@localMachine:~/poject/buildrepo`

If someone could give me some advice, point me in the right direction or tell me I'm silly for trying to do it this way it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you trying to create master or branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I had it pretty much right!
This helped me out:

http://thelucid.com/2008/12/02/git-setting-up-a-remote-repository-and-doing-an-initial-push/

I needed to create a bare git repo at the local location and then add it as a remote from my development location.

Ex:

`mkdir ~/project/buildrepo/proj.git
cd ~/project/buildrepo/proj.git
git init -bare
cd ~/project/dev
git remote add buildrepo usr@machine:~/project/buildrepo
git push buildrepo`